# how to understad a form is submitted in struts actions

Tags: struts2

In struts2 actions the injection is used for setting the property values of an action class, so the properties are updated by form fields on the form submission. To discover which form is submitted I create a method calling `isFormSubmitted()` and in there I check a redundant property created only for this motive. The property is updated in a hidden field. But I find this workout so dirty! I think that there must be a better way to solve this problem.

What I do is:

```
<s:form name="form1">
  <s:hidden name="submit" value="10" />
  ...other fields go here
</s:form>
```

in the action class I have `getSubmit`, `setSubmit` methods and the following method:

```
public boolean isFormSubmitted(){
  return (submit == 10);
}
```

Comment: "To discover which form is submitted" - your call one action from different forms and whant to know wich one submitted for some different logic in action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your can call different action methods in your action, not only "execute" method. Just put the parameter with the name like "method:actionMethodName" in your request. Here is example:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {    

  public String execute() {      
    // Base code
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public String one() {      
    // Code one
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public String two() {      
    // Code two
    return SUCCESS;
  }    

}
```

And here is jsp:

```
<s:form action="MyAction">
  <input type="submit" value="Call execute"/>
  <input type="submit" name="method:one" value="Call method one"/>
  <input type="submit" name="method:two" value="Call method two"/>
</s:>
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
<s:form action="MyAction" name="form0">
  <!-- call execute-->
</s:>

<s:form action="MyAction" name="form1">
  <!-- call method one-->
  <input type="hidden" name="method:one"/>
</s:>

<s:form action="MyAction" name="form2">
  <!-- call method two-->
  <input type="hidden" name="method:two"/>
</s:>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<s:form>` tag `action` attribute to submit to specific action.

```
<s:form action="action1">
  ...
</s:form>

<s:form action="action2">
  ...
</s:form>
```

See the `<s:form>` tag documentation: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/form.html.

**Update**

Then just use separate actions for loading and saving the user.

Comment: but you didn't get what I meant! I know the action attribute but imagine an editUser action. When the form hasn't been submitted I should load the user to the database while if the form has been submitted I should try to save the user in the database. How can I understand what I should do. Checking editUser form fields is so much dirties especially because later I decide to change the fields.  This was an example. In some pages I have different forms calling injecting to the same action. I'd rather to check sth like the form name. Not the hidden field!

Comment: @user1892555: Then just use separate actions for loading and saving the user.

Comment: Useless database load & remaining problem! Why? First we should go to editUser it loads and shows the form and on the submit goes to saveUser. Then saveUser on success/error should return to editUser to review. editUser always tries to load the user. There can be another scenario. If the user goes directly to saveUser action it will not understad if I have redirectd to it or a form has been submitted. On the other hand I will have to have 3 classes for one action. 1 parent class that extends ActionSupport and contains properties and getters and setters to avoid redundance. 2 children

Answer (score 0):

you should do the submission of the form something like this.

```
<s:form name="form1">
 <s:hidden name="submit" value="10" />
</s:form>
```

create a java script function

```
function onclick()
{
document.form1.submit();
}
```

then create getters & setters in action for hidden field

and in execute method

```
    public String execute()
    {
    setSubmit(10);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**Update :**

```
<a href="your_action_name"></a>
```

or

```
  <s:a href="your_action"></a>
```

Comment: and if the user disables the javascript?!

Comment: ok, then you can use anchor tag placed where you want to click,check the updated section

Comment: you mean I set <s:form name="foo" action="action1.action#ok"